# Find subnet mask of router

Tags: networking, router

So I have a router, which i cannot log into, because i've changed the password and i forgot it.

I am buying a new router now and want to change it, so i will probably need it's public ip address and subnet mask( and probably mac address ), so that I can surf the internet with my new router without calling my ISP for assistance.

I know it sounds crazy, but is there a way to find the subnet mask of the router( just to be clear this is different from the subnet mask of that my machine uses to connect to the router).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a dynamic Public IP for your modem from your ISP?

Comment: It ought to be listening to DHCP on the external port, so the point is moot really. It will find its own subnet mask. You can easily find your public IP address by typing "what's my IP address" straight into Google. You could have also hardware reset the old router to clear the password.

Comment: Actually my ISP is using static addresses for its clients. I have had problems with this in the past. I have to do the settings or it won't connect.

Comment: well, an interface's mask is not generally an externally observable phenomena. Many network architectures involve the changing the mask at different points in the network for purposes like route aggregation, scoped visibility, etc, so without access to the devices config, its not generally possible to tell. How about temporarily replacing the  existing router with a laptop so you can observe the DHCP settings it pulls from the ISP?